# What should I use to keep track of record modification (history for each row of each table)

Tags: database, database-design

Here is the story, I have a very classic database (relational), I store some data like EXAMPLE_TABLE(id, title, description, startDate, endDate, etc ...)

I have a lot of these tables and for each table I want to be able to track when the endDate has been changed or if it has been changed many time and by who.

Basically I want to create an history for each row of each table that I can later analyze (live or by batch) to answer some functional questions or even display some dashboard.

What is the best way to achieve that ? 
Should I use the same database ? and just create an "history" table for each table
Should I use a different database (still a relational one), to avoid disturbing the first one ?
What about a noSql DB for this purpose ? would it be a good choice and why ?

thanks for your advices

Comment: What about keeping a single table in which some table reference is kept to identify other table. Like `tblHistory` and fields - `[idHistory, idTableReff, modifiedBy, modifiedDate]` ?

Comment: That's another way of doing but I don't like the idea of using to many join, and in my case all the tables and data are different, for one entity I need to keep track of modification date, for another I need to keep track of a status